# Motor for large speed range

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing a chuck for which I need a motor which can go from 200rpm to 5000rpm. I tried a 1000KV BLDC with 12V supply, but the minimum rpm was around 1800. Also, I am not sure whether stepper motors are good for these high RPMs. Please suggest a way to achieve this much speed range.

Comment: You would probably want a spindle motor. E.g., google "Yaskawa spindle motors." People may feel that this is a shopping question, and close it. Not sure. But that is why I am just commenting and not answering. Stepper motor is NOT what you want.

Comment: Then again, it might be easier to control a simple brushed DC motor. So that is an option also if you are trying to DIY the speed controller.

Comment: What are you using as your ESC? You can certainly get a BLDC to rotate at very low rpm, but not usually with an RC type ESC.

Comment: 1000Kv means 1000 RPM per volt, right? So 1800 rpm minimum means OP was applying around 1.8V (roughly).

Comment: Consider using gears.

Comment: What power and torque do you need. If you need flattish power across range you need very large low end torque - which may require a motor of far more power at high speeds which is unused. An induction motor with variable speed drive can probably handle that (rather large) range. You can get significantly lower kV BLDCMs. Again - what power torque vs speed curve wanted.

Comment: What power and torque vs speed curve are wanted?

Comment: What power and torque vs speed curve are wanted?

Comment: What power and torque vs speed curve are wanted?

Comment: If you don't yet know how much torque you need, or how much power you need at various RPM, you should probably try to figure that out before you select a motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual spindle motor is a brushed DC permanent magnet motor. It's a tried and tested design, easy to control, and will run from standstill to high speed.

There are two types of BLDC, with and without Hall sensors. The unsensored type relies on rotation to generate enough feedback signal to control the commutation, hence the minimum speed with a standard ESC. A sensored BLDC will run down to zero speed with a suitable controller.

You could run an unsensored BLDC in stepper-motor mode at low speeds if you already have the motor, want to fill in the standstill to low speed region, have enough motor cooling and aren't too bothered about efficiency, and are happy to switch between a standard ESC and your custom low speed driver.

Standard stepper motors will not run to high speeds, this is a non-starter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try that